# Magento join query results

Tags: php, mysql, magento, join

I am running a join query on two tables in Magento, this is the query :

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/flat_shipment_track')->getCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()->join( array('shipment'=>
                 $this->getTable('sales/flat_shipment')), 'main_table.order_id = 
                 shipment.order_id', array('shipment.*'), 'schema_name_if_different');
```

I was expecting to see some rows from join, but when I do `var_dump($collection)` I am getting Object of `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Flat_Shipment_Track_Collection`, this is a big object but I don't see actual rows, some starting content is here :

```
object(Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Flat_Shipment_Track_Collection)#35 (36) {
  ["_eventPrefix":protected]=>
  string(36) "sales_flat_shipment_track_collection"
  ["_eventObject":protected]=>
  string(30) "flat_shipment_track_collection"
  ["_orderField":protected]=>
  string(8) "order_id"
  ["_salesOrder":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_model":protected]=>
  string(25) "sales/flat_shipment_track"
  ["_resourceModel":protected]=>
  string(25) "sales/flat_shipment_track"
  ["_resource":protected]=>
  object(Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Flat_Shipment_Track)#56 (20) {
    ["_eventPrefix":protected]=>
    string(34) "sales_flat_shipment_track_resource"
    ["_grid":protected]=>
    bool(false)
    ["_useIsObjectNew":protected]=>
    bool(true)
    ["_useIncrementId":protected]=>
    bool(false)
    ["_entityTypeForIncrementId":protected]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["_virtualGridColumns":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_gridColumns":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_eventObject":protected]=>
    string(8) "resource"
    ["_resources":protected]=>
    object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource)#134 (5) {
      ["_connectionTypes":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["_connections":protected]=>
      array(5) {
        ["core_write"]=>
        object(Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql)#104 (30) {
          ["_defaultStmtClass":protected]=>
          string(29) "Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql"
          ["_transactionLevel":protected]=>
          int(0)
          ["_connectionFlagsSet":protected]=>
          bool(true)
          ["_ddlCache":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["_bindParams":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["_bindIncrement":protected]=>
          int(0)
          ["_debug":protected]=>
          bool(false)
          ["_logQueryTime":protected]=>
          float(0.05)
          ["_logAllQueries":protected]=>
          bool(false)
          ["_logCallStack":protected]=>
          bool(false)
          ["_debugFile":protected]=>
          string(23) "var/debug/pdo_mysql.log"
          ["_debugIoAdapter":protected]=>
          NULL
          ["_debugTimer":protected]=>
          int(0)
          ["_cacheAdapter":protected]=>
          object(Varien_Cache_Core)#14 (6) {
            ["_backend":protected]=>
            object(Zend_Cache_Backend_File)#19 (3) {
              ["_options":protected]=>
              array(9) {
                ["cache_dir"]=>
                string(28) "/var/www/magento/var/cache/"
                ["file_locking"]=>
                bool(true)
                ["read_control"]=>
                bool(true)
                ["read_control_type"]=>
                string(5) "crc32"
                ["hashed_directory_level"]=>
                int(1)
                ["hashed_directory_umask"]=>
                int(511)
                ["file_name_prefix"]=>
                string(4) "mage"
                ["cache_file_umask"]=>
                int(384)
                ["metadatas_array_max_size"]=>
                int(100)
              }
              ["_metadatasArray":protected]=>
              array(1) {
                ["176_CORE_CACHE_OPTIONS"]=>
```

Class `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Flat_Shipment_Track_Collection` is created by me this is the content of this class :

```
class Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Flat_Shipment_Track_Collection
    extends Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection_Abstract
{

    protected $_eventPrefix    = 'sales_flat_shipment_track_collection';

    protected $_eventObject    = 'flat_shipment_track_collection';

    protected $_orderField     = 'order_id';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('sales/flat_shipment_track');
    }

    public function setShipmentFilter($shipmentId)
    {
        $this->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $shipmentId);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

How can I get the result of joining two table this query should return me 15,000 rows.  Thanks

Edit:

I am running this query :

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT sfs.`order_id`) 
            FROM livedb.`sales_flat_shipment_track` sfst
            JOIN livedb.`sales_flat_shipment` sfs ON sfs.`order_id` = sfst.`order_id`
```

this from console returns 15,000.

Comment: Try This code and view query result. `echo "<pre>";
print_r($collection->getData);
exit;`

Comment: `print_r($collection->getData);` is returnning empty because there is no getData attribute in the returned object.

Comment: Returning empty because of no match data from query if match condition then it return array of data collection.

Comment: I have added the query in question.

Comment: `print_r($collection->getFirstItem()->getData())` did the trick in older magentos. You could also iterate over the collection to use all the result (ie. in a table).

Comment: First try to `echo (string) $collection->getSelect();` after join and take SQL from output. Try to run this SQL and check results.